# Trying to align items horizontally on large displays, and vertically on small displays with bootstrap

Tags: html, css

On large displays: I have an image horizontally aligned with 2 headers.
On small displays: I'm trying to stack the headers underneath the image, aligned vertically.

I suspect it has something to do with either margins, flex direction, some type of align property. Idk.. I've tried a bunch of things, maybe just not the right combination of things. It's possible i'm just having a brain fart or something. Here's the code:

```
<section>
        <div class="container-md d-lg-flex align-items-center align-middle">
                <img src="images\logo2.png" class="img-adjustment">
                <div class="heading-wrapper">
                        <div class="display-4 montserrat text-nowrap heading-adjustment" style="">
                                Phoenix Master Meters
                        </div>
                        <h5 class="source-sans text-nowrap heading-adjustment">
                                Pipeline Consulting, Inspection, and Maintenance Services
                        </h5>
                </div>
        </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can implement Bootstrap Grid, which then will handle display for large and small screens.

Then, remove `text-nowrap` class in elements inside `heading-wrapper` div.

This is one example

```
<section>
        <div class="container-md d-lg-flex align-items-center align-middle">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-12">
                <img src="images\logo2.png" class="img-adjustment">
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-10 col-sm-12">
                <div class="heading-wrapper">
                        <div class="display-4 montserrat heading-adjustment" style="">
                                Phoenix Master Meters
                        </div>
                        <h5 class="source-sans heading-adjustment">
                                Pipeline Consulting, Inspection, and Maintenance Services
                        </h5>
                </div>
            </div>
          </div>


        </div>
</section>
```

Comment: This positioned the logo underneath the headers. When I reduce the screen size the headers do go under the logo, but they're not centered